# Simple python Webserver socket programming

Tags: python, sockets

I am having trouble getting my webserver to connect to my python and if I do, it goes straight to the IOError and prints out 404 Not Found instead of printing the html file I have.

I have tried running this code and fixing it for many days now but I just can't figure out the problem. I tried it on different computers and then one just a single computer and all I get is that it will skip to 404 Not found.

I used 127.0.0.1:6789/helloworld.html to connect it.

```
import sys

serverPort = 6789
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

#serverName = ''
serverSocket.bind(("",serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print ('the web server is up on port: ', serverPort)

while True:
 #Establish the connection
   print('Ready to serve...')
   (connectionSocket, addr) = serverSocket.accept()
   print("connection is from: " + str (addr))

   try:
         message = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
         filename = message.split()[1]
         f = open(filename[1:])

         outputdata = f.read()
         print ("output data is: ",outputdata)
         connectionSocket.send(('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n').encode())
         connectionSocket.send(message.encode())
         outputdata = f.read()

         for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode())
         connectionSocket.send(("\r\n").encode())

         connectionSocket.close()
   except IOError:
         connectionSocket.send(('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n').encode())
         connectionSocket.send(("<html><body><h1> 404 Not Found </h1></body></html>\r\n\r\n").encode())
         connectionSocket.close()
serverSocket.close()
sys.exit()
```

Then the html file I have is saved in the same folder as this webserver.py as helloworld.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1> Hello World </h1>
<h2> How are you? </h2>

</body>
</html>
```

I expected it to run in the browser as Hello World How are you, but the actual input was skipped to the 404 Not Found.

Comment: How does your html file connect to your web socket?

Comment: it's in the same folder as the web socket